# Factory Girl common root for an object graph

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

```
invitation ------>  event
  \                     \
  \/                    \/
 responder(person) ---->account
      \                  /\
       \                 /
       group-------------
```

I have the above association graph.
And the below factory code:

```
Factory.define :invitation do |i|
  i.association :event
  i.association :responder, :factory => :person
end


Factory.define :event do |e|
  e.association :account
end


Factory.define :person do |p|
  p.association :account
  p.association :group
end

Factory.define :group do |g|
  g.association :account
end
```

If I want to create an invitation with "Factory :invitation" then the account would be created more than once. And the unique fields for account are already taken by the second attempt.
Is there any clever and nice receipt for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the account of event in the `after_create` (or `after_build`) callback.

```
Factory.define :invitation do |i|
  i.association :event
  i.after_create { |i| i.responder = Factory(:person, :account => i.event.account) }
end
```

You'll have to modify the group factory in a similar way.

Comment: use after_build, that should be better.